# How to limit number of simultaneous connection in ssh2-sftp-client npm

Tags: node.js, npm, sftp, ssh2-sftp, ssh2-sftp-client

I am using ***ssh2-sftp-client*** for making an SFTP connection. I need to limit the number of simultaneous connections to ONE. I don't see such setting in the documentation https://github.com/theophilusx/ssh2-sftp-client. Please help